# Scapy send probe request and receive probe response

Tags: python, wifi, scapy

I am trying to do a job that send **802.11** probe request and receive probe response from. But the result is not good.

Here is my sending frame part, I use `Scapy` in python:

```
  class Scapy80211(): 
    def  __init__(self,intf='wlan0',ssid='test',\
          source='00:00:de:ad:be:ef',\
          bssid='00:11:22:33:44:55',srcip='10.10.10.10'):
    self.rates = "\x03\x12\x96\x18\x24\x30\x48\x60"
    self.ssid    = ssid
    self.source  = source
    self.srcip   = srcip
    self.bssid   = bssid
    self.intf    = intf
    self.intfmon = intf + 'mon'

    def ProbeReq(self,count=10,ssid='',dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', fc=0):
      if not ssid: ssid=self.ssid
      param = Dot11ProbeReq()
      essid = Dot11Elt(ID='SSID',info=ssid)
      rates  = Dot11Elt(ID='Rates',info=self.rates)
      dsset = Dot11Elt(ID='DSset',info='\x01')
      pkt = RadioTap()\
        /Dot11(type=0,subtype=4,FCfield=fc,addr1=dst,addr2=self.source,addr3=self.bssid)\
        /param/essid/rates/dsset

      print '[*] 802.11 Probe Request: SSID=[%s], count=%d' % (ssid,count)
      try:
        sendp(pkt,count=count,inter=0.1,verbose=1)
      except:
        raise

ssid = 'aa' #This is the AP I want to interact with
sdot11 = Scapy80211(intf='mon0')
sdot11.ProbeReq(ssid=ssid)
sniff(count=10, timeout=5, prn=PacketHandler, filter="type mgt subtype probe-resp")
```

I run the code for 20 times there is one time I can get the result.

Besides, the result is also a little strange, when I could receive the response, I often receive a lot at that time.

So, can anyone help me? How do you usually do the send and receive job?

---

I have changed my code to `srp()`. I remove the sniff() statement and replace the sendp() with srp(). And here is my result, I am quite confused about it.

```
[*] 802.11 Probe Request: SSID=[aa], count=10
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.

Received 0 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
[*] 802.11 Probe Request: SSID=[aa], count=10
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.

Received 12 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

I want to receive the probe response frame from the **aa**, the one I send probe request to.

So the result is no answer? And I am not sure is it related to that I did not fill in the right parameters like SSID, source, bssid. And should I change the destination from "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff" to the MAC address of **aa**?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm wrong, you are sending your probes, then sniffing the responses. If an answer arrives, it is likely that it arrives meanwhile.

You should probably use `srp()` function that does the job of sending frames and matching the answers.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did. I have changed my code to `srp()`, and I post the result and my uncertainly. Can you help see?

Answer (score 0):

Try your code:
if not ssid: ssid = self.ssid
instead of:
if ssid != "":ssid = self.ssid

I hope it will be helpful!